# SaltStack: Use regexps in pillar file

Tags: python, regex, jinja2, salt-stack

I would like to do some basic pillar value settings for all boxes so that I can use them later in a unified way. Our minions are usually named in this format:

```
<project>-<env>.<role>-<sequence>.<domain>
```

Example `pillar/base/top.sls`:

```
base:
    '*':
        - basics
    'I@project:mycoolproject and I@role:nginx':
        - etc.
```

Example `pillar/base/basics/init.sls`:

```
{% if '-live.' in grains['id'] %}
env: production
{% elif '-qa.' in grains['id'] %}
env: qa
{% elif '-staging.' in grains['id'] %}
env: staging
{% else %}
env:
{% endif %}

{% set role = re.match("(?:live|qa|staging)\.([a-z_\-]+)\-', grains['id']).group(1) -%}
role: {{ role }}
```

The `env` part obviously works but I can't get the regex working. As far as I understood there is no way to import python module (i.e. `import re`) in jinja template. Any suggestions how to get regex functionality available in the pillar file if possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, "no".  There is not a way to inject regex functionality directly into the jinja environment (I'm sure there's a way to extend jinja, but anyway..)

The way I addressed this was with an external module function, id_info.explode() and an external pillar.

Enable external modules on the master:

```
external_modules: /srv/extmod
```

External modules do not require any sort of special infrastructure--they are just regular python modules (not packages, mind you--the loader doesn't currently know how to properly side-load a package yet)

Put your python+regex logic there. Return a dictionary, assembled to your your liking.

Your external module would go in /srv/extmod/modules. You can call call this function from your pillar.sls

```
{% id_info = __salt__[id_info.explode()] -%}
{% subcomponent = id_info['subcomponent'] -%}
{% project = id_info['project'] -%}
```

etc...

A couple things to know:

- The salt-master has to be restarted when an external module is added or modified. There isn't a way that I know of to incite the equivalent of a saltutil.refresh_modules() call on the salt-master, so there ya go.
- The external_modules directive is not just for execution modules. In this scenario, you would also create `/srv/extmod/{pillar,runners,outputers,etc}`.
- These modules are only available on the master

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for but usable I guess. I'll try that later. Thanks!